# Set intercept in exponential decay

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit my data to an exponential model

```
y=exp(a-b*x)
```

The value of `y` in `x=0` must be exactly 13.75, so I want to set the intercept before I fit the data.

```
a=log(13.75)
```

I am using the function `gnm`. I have read that I am supposed to use `constrain` or `constrainTo` to set the coefficients; however, I can't understand how to do it.

```
x=seq(0,3120,120)

y= c(13.75, 13.74, 13.73, 13.71, 13.70, 13.69, 13.68,
     13.66, 13.65,13.64, 13.64, 13.63, 13.63, 13.62,
     13.62, 13.61, 13.61, 13.60,13.60, 13.60, 13.60,
     13.59, 13.59, 13.59, 13.59, 13.59, 13.59)

xl<-gnm(y ~ Exp(1 - x), verbose = FALSE,constrain=????)
```

#

Hi, everybody. Thank you very much. I've been working following your advice and I finally got a quite good fitting. Now I'll work on the weights to polish it. I did this:

```
xl<-gnm(y ~ Exp(1 + x) -1, verbose = FALSE,
constrain="Exp(.+x).Intercept",constrainTo=a,start=c(a,-0.05),
prior.weights=W,weights=W)
```

There was a big problem too. I needed to substract a number from y, in order to place the horizontal asymptote of my data at zero.

Comment: I get NA for the intercept and 2.4 for the other coefficient

Comment: I tried the first one and I think I have set the intercept. Now I get NA for the intercept and 2.4 for the other coefficient. However, the result doesn't fit to the original data.

Comment: I can't believe it is so difficult to fit an exponential...Maybe an exponential is not suitable. I am trying a fourth degree polynomial instead.

Comment: why not fit a log-linear model (logging both sides of your model)? in general the choice is nontrivial--exponentials can create numerical issues

Answer (score 1):

Using `-1` in the `Exp` tells the mode not to set an intercept term in the exponential. 
Try using this model: 
`Exp(1 + x) -1`, to remove the actual y intercept.

To set the intercept in the exponential, you can try:

```
xl<-gnm(y ~ Exp(1 + x) -1, verbose = FALSE,constrain="Exp(.+x).Intercept",constrainTo=a,start=c(a,-0.05))
xl
```

Had to input start parameters for the model to be estimated
To choose the constrained parameter interactively, you can also do:

```
xl<-gnm(y ~ Exp(1 + x) -1, verbose = FALSE,constrain="[?]",constrainTo=a,start=c(a,-0.05))
```

Comment: Hi, everybody. Thank you very much. I've been working following your advice and I finally got a quite good fitting. Now I'll work on the weights to polish it. I did this: xl<-gnm(y ~ Exp(1 + x) -1, verbose = FALSE,
        constrain="Exp(.+x).Intercept",
        constrainTo=a,start=c(a,-0.05),
        prior.weights=W,weights=W)